# kivy scroll layout issue

Tags: python, kivy

```
class Template_Screen (Screen):
    pass
```

Above is the class which i have added into a App class as follows

```
class MAKE_HTML(App):
    """
    Still i need to write it fully.... Thanks for patience.....
    """
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Template_Screen(name='Select Template'))
```

I am using the kv file which is as follows

```
#the below screen gives the template
<Template_Screen>
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y:True
        do_scroll_x: False
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            cols:1
            height:self.minimum_height
            BoxLayout:
                Image:
                    source: "Images/Templates Pictures/Temp-1.png"
            Label:
                text:"Some sort of text\n Some text"
```

**Problems:**

1. When I scroll, the scroll first scrolls and then goes up even if i do not scroll up. i.e, After scrolling down-> Automatically goes up.
2. The image is not visible. I want the image to be 1/2 the size of screen.

[image]

I want to scroll with above like o/p.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `effect_cls` of a `ScrollView` is `DampedScrollEffect`, which the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#overscroll-effects) describes as:

> DampedScrollEffect: The current default. Allows the user to scroll
> beyond the normal boundaries, but has the content spring back once the
> touch/click is released.

So that is the automatic scrolling effect that you see. You can eliminate that behavior by using `ScrollEffect` as the `effect_cls`, but that will also prevent you from scrolling when the contents do not fill the `ScrollView`

When you use `height:self.minimum_height` for a `GridLayout`, you must provide a `height` for each child. Since you want the `Image` to be half the size of the `Screen`, you can use a `kv` like this:

```
#the below screen gives the template
<Template_Screen>
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_y:True
        do_scroll_x: False
        effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            cols:1
            height:self.minimum_height
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: root.width/2, root.height/2
                Image:
                    source: "mages/Templates Pictures/Temp-1.png"
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
            Label:
                text:"Some sort of text\\n Some text"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: self.texture_size
```

Comment: However, the image does not work as intended.

Comment: No issues i have found it... TQ